# How to delete css style "body ::-webkit-scrollbar" by javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Now the webpage uses the style for scroll which was in the node-modules, I want to delete the property "-webkit-apperance" in my code, how can I do this?

```
<div class="fs-key" id="fs-id" >....</div>
```

```
body ::-webkit-scrollbar{
   -webkit-apperance: none;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Just to clarify - the default setting for -webkit-appearance is auto - do you want to ensure that it always has this value and that nothing can change it, or do you want it to be changed to none? Also can you say what the significance of the HTML you have shown is? What is its connection with -webkit-appearance? Are you running some pre-processor?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new rule for the elements you want to delete the property for like this:

```
body ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
}

.reset-scrollbar::webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: initial;
}
```

So the only thing you have to do is add the reset-scrollbar class to the classlist.

Comment: thank you ,but other body ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{ border-radius:5px} was still 
take effect after “-webkit-appearance: initial”  , unless the “-webkit-appearance” was deleted already.